# I want to Change The sprite through code (I tried this.GameObject<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteName)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I tried  `this.GameObject<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteName;` but it doesn't seem to work it just give me the error:

> The type or namespace name 'sprite' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
public void TheBlueCircle()
{
    this.GameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = BlueCircle;
}
```

Comment: This needs more context for the question to be understood.

Comment: I want to change the sprite using a button i have made a variable (public Sprite blueCircle;) and referenced it as well but it still shows the error

Comment: But your error is not on BlueCircle/blueCircle. With a namespace error, the context means, at the very least, you list of using directives.

Comment: Please add a complete code

Answer (score 0):

`this.GameObject`is incorrect. You need to use the instance of GameObject and not the class so it will be `this.gameObject.GetComponent<>()`

In many cases, `this.gameObject` is not required, so you can probably just write `GetComponent<>()`

Comment: (ofcourse I doubt this is the case here but) what if `GameObject` was a field of OP's class? like e.g. `public GameObject GameObject;` ;)

Comment: Yes you can use variable with the same name as classes but it's definitely not recommended ...